# Run SHOW TABLES  with only part of table name

Tags: mysql

I want select tables on my database but no all tables.
The tables that part of name is like "tt".

Example:
Table list: (`users`, `tt_content`, `contact`, `tt_sub`)

I want to select just `tt_content` and `tt_sub`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

`show tables like 'tt%';` ought to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're using MySQL since that's the only DBMS that I know of that uses the `SHOW TABLES;` command.

In that case, I think you're looking for:

```
 SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tt%';
```